# HTML like frames in android native app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am to develop an android app.

I have a common header and common footer (and these header footer will have common button which will be doing a specific task).

The app will be having more than 25 activities and I don't want to copy the same XML and same java code in all the activities.

What are the other ways in which I can create the header and footer separate and can re-use them in all the activities?

It is much like using frames in html where we have common pages differently prepared and use them together in a single one

Thanks mates,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an include tag to refer to the header and footer layouts.

```
<include
 layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"
 android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_ok" />
```

Comment: That's working like a charm!
But could you please also tell me that how can I separate their java code(event calls) in a separate java file?

Comment: Make a class with a method (probably just a static method) that takes takes a Context that will get the views by id and add event handlers.

Comment: Although I've did the same before your comment but I really appreciate your help.
:)